# html-pdf with ejs template

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

In my application, when a user passes a test, there will automatically be generated a diploma (`pdf`). This I accomplish by using the `html-pdf` `node-module`, which retrieves the html file and makes it into a pdf.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    pdf = require('html-pdf'),
    path = require('path'),
    ejs = require('ejs');


var html = fs.readFileSync('./phantomScripts/certificate.html', 'utf8');
var options = { filename: 'businesscard.pdf', format: 'A4', orientation: 'portrait', directory: './phantomScripts/',type: "pdf" };

pdf.create(html, options).toFile(function(err, res) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
         console.log(res);
    });
```

This conversion, from `html` to `pdf`, works perfectly and looks really good. Now what I want is to make the `template` a little bit more dynamic, meaning that depending on the user, their name appears in the `pdf`.

I have work once with `ejs` to generate an email template, so I was thinking that my problem could be solved with that, but as mentioned I'm haven't work that much with `ejs` and can't figure out how to send `data` into my `ejs` file?

Answer (score 8):

```
ejs.renderFile('./path/to/template-file.ejs', {data : {firstname: 'Tom', lastname: 'Hanks'}, function(err, result) {
    // render on success
    if (result) {
       html = result;
    }
    // render or error
    else {
       res.end('An error occurred');
       console.log(err);
    }
});
```

I replaced my `var html = fs.readFileSync('./phantomScripts/certificate.html', 'utf8');` code with the above code, and it works as I want it to.

Comment: how can we add image in the template-file.ejs content? for example image is inside uploads/image.png

Comment: hi bro I don't know whether its too late for an answer. YOU CAN ADD AN IMG TAG IN ejs file with correct url and enter image.

Comment: I was facing a similar issue and your code snippet helped me. thank you.